# App Data Security- Dont want user to access my android app files

Tags: android

I don't want the user to access my App files in the computer or laptop. Is there any way to solve this issue?
Other than using Encryption or Decryption.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If hiding them is an option to you, you can do the following (taken from the [official docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)):

> Hiding your files from the Media Scanner
>
> Include an empty file named .nomedia in your external files directory
>   (note the dot prefix in the filename). This prevents media scanner
>   from reading your media files and providing them to other apps through
>   the MediaStore content provider. However, if your files are truly
>   private to your app, you should save them in an app-private directory.